# Python Ctypes x64 OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000008

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to comunicate with an infrared camera, using python interface and ctypes to call sdk functions in dlls. There is one function in C++(only .h files are given)

`int sdk_start_url(IRNETHANDLE p, char* ip);`

where `IRNETHANDLE` is defined as void* type.
I try to call that function using

`IrCamCtrldll.sdk_start_url.argtypes = (c_void_p, c_char_p)`

`ret = IrCamCtrldll.sdk_start_url(handle, c_char_p(b'192.168.1.123'))`

Error appears as:

`OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000008`

As I have used `handle` in other similiar functions, errors should NOT appeard with that. So there is something wrong with the second parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have documentation for this function?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown, although wrapping `b'192.168.1.123'` in `c_char_p` is unnecessary.  What's the value of `handle`?

Comment: Thank you all. I found the problem. Surely the code is correct. One key step has been forgotten thus I cannot open the camera.